# Compare products id in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, compare, selection

Is there any way to select only product Id for compare items in collection Like:

```
$compare = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection();
$compare_product = array();
$compareList = '';
foreach ($compare as $product) {
    $compareList .= $product->getId();
    $compare_product[] = $product->getId();
}
```

**instead:**

```
$compare = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('product_id');
```

Comment: Please elaborate more about your question.

Comment: Did you checked addFieldToFilter( instead of addAttributeToFilter(?

Comment: @ArifAhmad, yes nothing changed, When I print query, It show multiple column selected

Comment: Can you try this :

$compare = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection();
$productIdsCollection = $compare->addAttributeToSelect('product_id');

I don't have a M1 setup so can't see what is going wrong but this should technically work.

I believe you have attribute - product_id

Comment: No difference, Still show the same, I already applied the same. You can see in my question.